# How do I read in and validate a csv file's raw data in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, csv

(* raw data as in the way it appears when you open a csv file using notepad as opposed to seeing columns in Excel)

I need to validate .csv files when they are uploaded to a web application, but I realized the information I need to validate does not appear in the csv file when i open it up in Excel, however I can see the data when I open the .csv file with notepad.

Here is a sample of the code that appears when I open a csv file in notepad:

```
&lt;tr&gt;
&lt;td style=&quot;padding-left:10px;font-family: Verdana; font-size: x-small;&quot;&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;text-align:center; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small; color: #663399; font-weight: bold;&quot;&gt;                                                      
&lt;br /&gt;
&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.google.com&quot;&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
&lt;/p&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;/tr&gt;
```

The part i need to validate is 
`http://www.google.com` which I believe i know how to do, the problem is how do I read the csv file's code in my application ?

Thank you

Comment: ...that's not a csv-file. That's HTML-encoded HTML.

Comment: That part of the csv file is created from a form where there is a textbox containing html code. This is probably why it doesnt appear in Excel when i open the csv file.

Comment: @SQLNoob The data needs to be properly formatted as a .csv file. That isn't .csv data. You need to pass the outputs of the form, then operate on the data.

Comment: So is there no way to take (any) file and validate its source code?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by validate, and since you don't have a CSV file your question really makes no sense. When you ask a question here, consider that we have no idea what you're trying to do and you need to explain as you would to someone that doesn't know what's going on. That means be clear but still keep it concise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a CSV file. Looks like HTML to me.
What you can do is simply read that file as text and then simply do the operations you want to perform.